# React native Unexpected token function

Tags: react-native, build

I did `npm audit fix` and after that action, I get this message on build:

```
/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/cliEntry.js:168
async function run() {
      ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alexfrangulev/ReactApps/Morato/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:5:40)
Process terminated. Press <enter> to close the window
```

My package.json looks like:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

Id someone can give me a clue would be wonderful. 
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What is the version of node.js you have installed?

Comment: Hi, I am using nvm the default one is 6.10.2 but when I run react-native run-ios I am changing it on 10.13.0